# Lodash - Conditionally Return Object from a Map Method

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to iterate through an array, run a calculation, and if the condition is true for the result, return a new object.  `_.filter(...)` would not work here, since the iterator function must return either `true` or `false`.

```
_.map(people, function(person) {

    var age = calculateAge(person.birthDate);

    if (age > 50) {
        return {person: person, age: age};
    }

});
```

I've tried searching all over, including the documentation, but I haven't found a way to do this well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like maybe you want `reduce` and not `map`:

```
var newArray = _.reduce(people, function(results, person) {
  var age = calculateAge(person.birthDate);
  if (age > 50) {
     results.push({ person: person, age: age });
  }
  return results;
}, []);
```

<s>Also if you are ES6+ and/or using Babel, this might be a good use for list comprehensions:</s>

```
let newArray = [for (person of people)
                if (calculateAge(person.birthDate) > 50)
                { person: person, age: calculateAge(person.birthDate) }
               ];
```

**Update**: List comprehensions have been dropped from from Babel 6.  The ES2015 version would look like:

```
const newArray = people.reduce((results, person) => {
  const age = calculateAge(person.birthDate);
  return (age > 50) ? [...results, { person, age }] : results;
}, []);
```

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: In both your examples, where does the variable `age` come from?

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you:

```
var sorted = _.filter(people, function(person) {

    var age = calculateAge(person.birthDate);

    if (age > 50) {
      return true;
    }
});

var newArray = _.map(sorted, function(person) {

   var age = calculateAge(person.birthDate);

   return {person: person, age: age};
});
```

This will first filter the list and then return a new array with the objects of the people whos age is above 50.

Comment: The variable `age` is not defined in the callback to `map`. Also, why would you need to do another check on age if you've already filtered the youngsters out? Also, `return age > 50;` is more idiomatic. To avoid recalculating age, you could stick it on the object in the filter, That would also allow you to use `pick` to return from the map.

Comment: I had the same issue as what @torazaburo mentioned. Ideally I would want to make a database call instead of the `calculateAge(...)` method, so I would want to avoid querying the DB twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
people = _.pluck(
                _.filter(
                        _.map(people, function(person) {
                            return { person: person, age: calculateAge(person.birthDate) };
                        }), 
                        function(person) {
                            return person.age > 50;
                        }
                ), 
                "person"
        );
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmgt3hLt/)

Comment: You can chain methods instead of nesting them in lodash : ))